# Can't access a MultiIndex DataFrame with level names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to use MultiIndexing for the first time and I don't get why I can't index the DataFrame with the mnemonic names directly rather than through the .loc method like I can when I'm using single level indexing and as it shows in the documentation and several examples I've run into online.

Following is some simplified code and the output from the 2 methods:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ext = ['ms0', 'ms1', 'ms2']
node = ['supply', 'vdd', 'id0']
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ext, node],names=('extension', 'nodes'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(9, 1), index=index)
df

                           0
extension   nodes   
      ms0  supply   2.730935
              vdd  -1.771695
              id0   1.644740
      ms1  supply   1.086473
              vdd   0.234862
              id0   0.910154
      ms2  supply  -0.274787
              vdd   0.450530
              id0   0.197895
```

The following works:

```
df.loc['ms0']

                    0
     nodes  
    supply   2.730935
       vdd  -1.771695
       id0   1.644740
```

But this does not:

```
df['ms0']

...
D:\Apps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in 
get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:
-> 2527                 return 
self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2528 
   2529         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, 
tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: 'ms0'
```

The documentation for [MultiIndexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex) shows this example:

```
In [25]: df['bar']
Out[25]: 
second       one       two
A       0.895717  0.805244
B       0.410835  0.813850
C      -1.413681  1.607920
```

So why doesn't it work in this case?

Comment: 'bar' in that example is a column of the dataframe.  The `df['ms0']` syntax is looking for a column.  The loc format is looking for the index and optionally a column: `df.loc['ms0']` is the same as `df.loc['ms0',0]`.

Comment: To access by level you can use the xs syntax like: `df.xs('ms0',level=0)` and `df.xs('supply',level=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using df['ms0'] will select the 'ms0' column, which is not in the DataFrame shown. On the other hand, df.loc['ms0'] will select the row with the index 'ms0', which is valid.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html